# How to remove a fold from within a for-comprehension?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I have the following snippet in Scala using Scalaz and Task/EitherT:

```scala
def myMethod(request: MyRequest) : EitherT[Task, Failure, Success] =
    EitherT[Task, Failure, Success](
      for {
        aamOpt <- async.findUser(request)
        aamEith <- Task.now(aamOpt.\/>(NoUserFound()))
        result <- aamEith.fold(err => Task.now(-\/(err)), aam => process(aam)).run)
      } yield result)
```

Where `async.findUser` returns a `Task[Option[MyUser]]` and `process(aam)` returns `EitherT[Task, Failure, Success]`. These return types are needed as these methods interact (down the line) with external services.

Is there any way to simplify the last line of the for comprehension into something nicer? I mean this one:

```scala
result <- aamEith.fold(err => Task.now(-\/(err)), aam => process(aam)).run)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably immediately lift the result from `async.findUser` into the relevant `EitherT` monad and then just `flatMap`:

```
def myMethod(request: MyRequest): EitherT[Task, Failure, Success] =
  EitherT.eitherT[Task, Failure, MyUser](
    async.findUser(request).map(_.\/>(NoUserFound()))
  ).flatMap(process)
```

This is untested but something like it should more or less work.

Comment: yes, that works, got stuck on trying to fit a for comprehension in there but there's no need. Thanks a million :)